# $3$ digit number being subtracted by its digits

Tags: number-theory

This question is an AMC style question. The question is this:

> If the integer $A$ is reduced by the sum of its digits, the result is $B$. If $B$ is increased by the sum of its ($B$'s) digits, the result is $A$. Compute the largest $3$-digit number $A$ with this property.

I would like to know how you do this question.

Comment: Try to represent $A$ as $x*10^2+y*10+z$.

Comment: Helps to note that $A$ and the sum of the digits of $A$ are congruent $\pmod 9$, which implies that $A$ must be $0\pmod 9$.  At a minimum, that speeds the search.

Comment: Well it is usual on the site for you to suggest some thoughts of your own. I don't know why you are engaging with this, but if it is developmental you will get very little out of it unless you give it some substantial thought and effort of your own. Solving such questions involves developing your own mathematical imagination and intuition. I don't think this is hard when you know how to do it - the challenge is finding the way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows that the digit sum of $B$ is the same as that of $A$. That measn that $A\equiv B\pmod 9$, so the digit sum is a multiple of $9$.
On the other hand, the digit sum of $B<A<1000$ cannot be larger than $9+9+8=26$. Hence the common digit sum is either $9$ or $18$.
The largest candidate for $A$ with such a digit sum is $A=990$ and leads to $B=A-18=972$, which works fine.